# Как объединить значения из нескольких полей в одно?

Tags: mysql

Есть у меня таблица product и в ней есть несколько полей: a1,a2,a3. Поля a1,a2 со значениями. Поле a3 пустое. В него нужно объединить значения полей a1 и a2.

Объединяю значения a1,a2

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', a1, a2) FROM product
```

Но не пойму, как мне их записать в поле a3.

```
AS a3
```

Не помогает. 
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так для изменения записи вам нужно update. Select это выборка

```
UPDATE product
Set a3=CONCAT_WS(' ', a1, a2)
```

Comment: В Workbench через SELECT просматривал результат. Спасибо за Ваш ответ, работает.

Comment: @PiT Ну так пометьте вопрос решённым. Галка под количеством голосов...

Comment: таймер же, сразу нельзя